# Is it better to keep String constant in properties file or as static value

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to figure out whether it is a better idea to keep String Constants as static value or in a properties file. If i keep in properties file, will it be costly to read always from properties file.

What will be better in-terms of performance.

Comment: We're conflating a few things here.  A string literal constant is something that is available at compile time, and can be read to represent something important (to avoid magic Strings).  Reading a value from a property file represents either internationalization or a system property, which is available at runtime.  Do you want to store system properties, internationalized text, or have a quick and convenient way to reference all of your static final String literals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance is not the key... Design is the one.
Is your String a property of your application or not?

But the answer of your question is: of course, reading a static field is faster than reading from a file. 'seems obvious

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what you want ?

if you want the property to be accessed by all class and can be changed you use static

if you don't want your property to be changed you can use a constant one

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by constant.

If it is actually a constant then it is best stored in an `enum`.

If it is some sort of property - i.e. something that might be changed then a properties file is best.

Performance shouldn't be a concern here.